How to Implement NgRx Effect to Conditionally Trigger Modal Based on Product Price?
I want to check if the cost of the product is over 10 using NgRx state management. Then, if the product value is over 10 I want to show the
sval 

(sweetalert) element.
I have this code in reducer.ts:
public interface IProductsList{
  items: IProductListItem[]
}

public interface IProductListItem{
  price: int;
  name: string
}

So I create actions:
export const openPriceModal = createAction('[Products]')
export const openPriceModalSuccess = createAction('[Products]')
export const openPriceModalFailed = createAction('[Products]')

In the reducer I have these selectors:
export interface IProductsRequestState {
  selectedItem: IProductListItem
  list: IProductsList
}

export const getSelectedProductsRequestList = createSelector(getSelectedProductsRequestList , state => state.list)
  export const getSelectedProductsRequest = 
  createSelector(getSelectedProductsRequest, state => state.selectedItem )

Now I want to write an effect.ts that opens a modal depending on the prices:
openPriceModal = createEffect(() => 
  this.action$.pipe(ofType(openPriceModal), withLatestForm(() => {
..
})))

If it wasn't for store management, I would write it like this:

Get the list of items

Iterate through the list of this item and compare the price property

Return an element based on the result


I don't know how to implement this using NgRx.
All the logic has to be inside NgRx, and no logic should be in the component.

You can use selector to achieve just that.
So you can create a custom selector that check if the cost of the product is over 10 or not.
Example:
// selector.ts
export const getSelectProductOver10 = createSelector(
  getSelectedProductsRequestList,
  (product) => product.items.length > 10,
);

// effect.ts
  openPriceModal = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(openPriceModal),
        withLatestFrom(this._store.pipe(select(getSelectProductOver10))),
        map(([, isOver10]) => {
          if (isOver10) {
            // call the service to open the modal (sweetalert)
            ....
          }
       .....


thanks sir for answer, but i have to use effects

yes you can use effect to keep your component more simple.
